# Got django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I found a Django project and failed to get it running in Docker container in the following way:

1. `git clone git clone https://github.com/NAL-i5K/django-blast.git`
2. `$ cat requirements.txt` in this files the below dependencies had to be updated:

   - psycopg2==2.8.6

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y postgresql-client
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/django
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/i5k
```

For `docker-compose.yml` I use:

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./scripts/install-extensions.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/install-extensions.sql

    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
```

```
$ cat scripts/install-extensions.sql 
CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
```

I had to change:

```
$ vim i5k/settings_prod.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '5432',
        }
}
```

Next, I ran `docker-compose up --build`

```
web_1  | Performing system checks...
web_1  | 
web_1  | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
web_1  | Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f8a9733a6d0>
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
web_1  |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
web_1  |     self.check_migrations()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 168, in check_migrations
web_1  |     executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 19, in __init__
web_1  |     self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 47, in __init__
web_1  |     self.build_graph()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 191, in build_graph
web_1  |     self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations
web_1  |     self.ensure_schema()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 49, in ensure_schema
web_1  |     if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 162, in cursor
web_1  |     cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 135, in _cursor
web_1  |     self.ensure_connection()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
web_1  |     self.connect()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 98, in __exit__
web_1  |     six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
web_1  |     self.connect()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 119, in connect
web_1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 176, in get_new_connection
web_1  |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
web_1  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
web_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_1  |    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
web_1  |    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web_1  | could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
web_1  |    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
web_1  |    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Never used docker before but from some searching the `environment` part of the configuration is supposed to be nested with key value pairs instead of being an array? Also you specify something and use something else in the settings, `django_i5k` is the name of the db yet in the settings you use `postgres`, next the user is `django` yet again in the settings you use `postgres`?

Comment: Your host is dbik not db.

Comment: Thank you, I fix the errors and updated my question. Unfortunately, the error remained. What did I miss?

Comment: With these kinds of issues, where there's multiple parts in which there may be errors: when you make corrections update everything, including the logs. Your log still says it tried to connect to "localhost" and not "db". If it is still trying to connect to localhost, please mention that. It indicates that `settings_prod` is ignored or its values overwritten by another settings file.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in my comment the `environment` part of the configuration are key-value pairs, not an array of key-value pairs. Hence your `docker-compose.yml` file should be:

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./scripts/install-extensions.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/install-extensions.sql

    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
```

Comment: Thank you, I took your `docker-compose.yml` file but I got again `django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
`. What did I miss?

Comment: Suggestion: "supposed to be nested" -> "are key/value pairs, not an array of key/value pairs".

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand it.